# User32 - Switchdesktop works but switches back to normal desktop after couple of seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, desktop-application

I am using desktop switch in my C# program.

Desktop switches normally but after 1 or 2 seconds switches back to normal desktop.
Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

First i get normal desktop. Then i create new empty desktop to insert my form. Then i switch to empty desktop and set it to thread desktop, then i run application.

My code like below;

```
private Task StartStaTask(Action action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action();

                tcs.SetResult(null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tcs.SetException(e);
            }
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }

public void RunFormInKioskMode(Form frm)
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr defaultDesktop = GetDefaultDesktop();

            IntPtr blackoutDesktop = CreateNewBlackoutDesktop();

            User32.SwitchDesktop(blackoutDesktop);

            var staTask = StartStaTask(() =>
            {
                User32.SetThreadDesktop(blackoutDesktop);

                ///Desktop switch completed, run form in new restricted desktop

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(frm);
            });

            Task.WhenAll(staTask).Wait();

            ///Windows form completed its operation, return back to old desktop

            User32.SwitchDesktop(defaultDesktop);

            User32.SetThreadDesktop(defaultDesktop);

            User32.CloseDesktop(blackoutDesktop);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Instance.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

private IntPtr CreateNewBlackoutDesktop()
    {
        try
        {
            return User32.CreateDesktop(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint)DesktopAccess.LimitedAccess, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Instance.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

private IntPtr GetDefaultDesktop()
    {
        try
        {
            return User32.GetThreadDesktop(Kernel32.GetCurrentThreadId());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Instance.Write(ex.ToString());
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: Application runs in different computers by the way. When i test it in my virtual machine, it stays. When i test it in my physical computer it fails after 1-2 seconds.

Comment: I think i come out with a new problem. I listened desktop switch system events. I ended up with a thread id that ESET antivirus process eguiProxy.exe is switching back to normal desktop. When i remove ESET from my system, my code works. What is this, how can i make this work?